# Exploiting the compactness of the unit circle to prove the following proposition.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that *a locally convex topological vector space is equivalent to  a semi-normed topological vector space*. I have worked through the proof but I am unsure because of the following hint:

> Use the compactness of the  unit circle over the complex field to show that every convex neighbourhood of $0$ contains a balanced convex neighbourhood of $0$

My proof does not make use of the hint so I am a bit confused.

The following sketch is the argument I have been playing with:

As the unit circle, $C$ is compact, we have a finite subcover. Choose $\lambda_i$ from each open set in the finite subcover. Let $U$ be a convex neighbourhood of $0$. I am guessing we can use the finite $\lambda_i$ to state that  $ U \subset \bigcup\limits_{\lambda_i \in C}\lambda_iU $, hence is compact. Next, we prove that $U = \lambda_iU$ thus showing that $U$ is balanced. Exploiting the finite intersection property for compact sets we can conclude that $\bigcap\limits_{\lambda_i \in C} \lambda_iU \neq \emptyset$. As intersection of convex and balanced sets is a convex and balanced, we have proven what was required.

I am not sure I am correct, would it be possible for someone to give me the correct argument.

Thank you for your time in answering my doubt.